# Is it a good idea to make one graphql response type for all queries and mutations?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

What if we make one type that includes all state user can get from the backend. Lets call it `AppState`.

And there will be only one query `getAppState`, and all mutations will return `AppState` as well so that clients can access any field they need, and if you use [apolloClient](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client), clients' cache will update automatically.

We can get all state on user login without any problem.

Is it a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

Following this pattern would exactly contradict the reasoning behind the existence of GraphQL itself.
The idea is for your queries and mutations to exactly fit a pre-defined expected outcome. If you actually implemented such a concept, unless you provide **all** the data a query or mutation expects, it will throw an error. Subsequently, if you would actually end up trying it, you will quickly realize how cluttered and resource-heavy it actually is. Imagine fetching all your databases with each request because of this schema .... that would be awful.

Comment: But if client requests only what it needs it will fetch only db that you need, doesn't it? If you resolve different props separately.